# PHP MySQL search engine mutiple inputs

Tags: php, mysql, search

Before asking anything i would like to say that i am very very new to php with almost no experience.I have made database table which involves infromation/details about jobs being done on ships.

MY code :

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

require 'db/connect.php';
include 'header.php';
require 'functions/safety.php';

$records = array();

$user = trim($_POST['user']);
$customer  = trim($_POST['customer']);
$vessel         = trim($_POST['vessel']);
$country    = trim($_POST['country']);
$port = trim($_POST['port']);
$eta = trim($_POST['eta']);
$service_station = trim($_POST['service_station']);
$type_of_service = trim($_POST['type_of_service']);
$case_reference = trim($_POST['case_reference']);
$status = trim($_POST['status']);

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pelates 
                            WHERE user = '{$user}'
                            OR customer = '{$customer}'
                            OR vessel = '{$vessel}'
                            OR country = '{$country}'
                            OR port = '{$port}'
                            OR eta = '{$eta}'
                            OR service_station = '{$service_station}'
                            OR type_of_service = '{$type_of_service}'
                            OR case_reference = '{$case_reference}'
                            OR status = '{$status}'")) {
        if($results->num_rows) {
            while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
                $records[] = $row;
            }
            $results->free();
        }
    }
}   

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Search jobs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syles.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>  

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Vessel</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Port</th>
                <th>Eta</th>
                <th>Service station</th>
                <th>Type of service</th>
                <th>Case reference</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
                foreach($records as $r) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="green"><?php echo  escape($r->user); ?></td>
                        <td class="blue"><?php echo  escape($r->customer); ?></td>
                        <td class="green"><?php echo  escape($r->vessel); ?></td>
                        <td class="blue"><?php echo  escape($r->country); ?></td>
                        <td class="green"><?php echo  escape($r->port); ?></td>
                        <td class="blue"><?php echo  escape($r->eta); ?></td>
                        <td class="green"><?php echo  escape($r->service_station); ?></td>
                        <td class="blue"><?php echo  escape($r->type_of_service); ?></td>
                        <td class="green"><?php echo  escape($r->case_reference); ?></td>
                        <td class="blue"><?php echo  escape($r->status); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </br><a href="http://prinseapals-marine.com/filing/search.php" id="clear_button" class="button">Clear all</a>

    <hr>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="user">User</label>
            <select name="user" id="user">
                <option value="">Any</option>
                <option value="VAK">VAK</option>
                <option value="DTS">DTS</option>
                <option value="SVAK">SVAK</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="customer">Customer</label>
            <input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="vessel">Vessel</label>
            <input type="text" name="vessel" id="vessel" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="country" id="country" autocomplete="off"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="port">Port</label>
            <input type="text" name="port" id="port" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="eta">ETA</label>
            <input type="text" name="eta" id="eta" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="service_station">Service station</label>
            <input type="text" name="service_station" id="service_station" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="type_of_service">Type of service</label>
            <input type="text" name="type_of_service" id="type_of_service" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="case_reference">Case reference</label>
            <input type="text" name="case_reference" id="case_reference" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field" id="radio">
            <label>Pending</label>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="pending"/></br>
            <label>Offer</label>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="offer"/></br>
            <label>Order</label>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="order"/></br>
            <label>Lost</label>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="lost"/></br>
            <label>Postponed</label>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="postponed"/></br>
            <label>Declined</label>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="declined"/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search database" class="button" name="search">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that because in `$db->query("SELECT...")` i used OR between my variables when i try to search for user=Steven and status=Pending for example, it gets me all the results that have Steven as a user or Pending as a status and NOT the results that have Steven AND Pending as user and status.

So i tried using AND between my variables and then i got an other problem. Lets say i search again for user = Steven and status = Pending. The problem is that because i only fill in 2 from the 10 available search inputs and becasue there is no NOTHING value in any field in my database  i get no results because the programm is searching for a job with Steven as a user, Pending as a status, NOTHING as country, NOTHING as vessel and goes on...

I know that my question may be dumb or too easy to answer but please forgive me cause as i mentioned at the beginning i am REALLY new to php like 4 days-new. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me work around this guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you populate your variables from `$_POST` data conditionally, so that each variable will be set to `false` if it is blank. Then, exclude false values from your SQL query.

That way, your query will only include values that have been populated in your form. Inputs that were left blank will not affect the query.

Something like this:

```
// build array of field names
$fields=array('user','customer','vessel','country',
             'port','eta','service_station','type_of_service',
             'case_reference','status');


// initialize empty array for WHERE clauses
$wheres=array();

// loop through field names, get POSTed values,
// and build array of WHERE clauses, excluding false values
foreach ($fields as $field) {

  // get existing field value from POST, mark missing or empty value as FALSE
  ${$field} = isset($_POST[$field]) && trim($_POST[$field])!=''
      ? trim($_POST[$field]) : false;

  // add to array of WHERE clauses only if value is not FALSE
  if (${$field}) { $wheres[]="$field='".${$field}."'"; }

}

// build SELECT statement from WHERE clauses
$sql="SELECT * FROM pelates WHERE ".
     (!empty($wheres) ? implode(" AND ",$wheres) : '1=1').
     ";";

// preview your query on screen
echo "<p>$sql</p>";
```

Comment: Your solution works like a charm i am really grateful for your fast reply. But because as i mentioned above i am really new in PHP i cant understand all of it (although i must admit you really tried to explain). In fact your answer made feel bad for even trying to make the web application i want:(   Thanks again:P

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't feel bad, it's great to be learning. If there's something puzzling you but you want to understand, feel free to ask.